# Tkinter background progressbar function while another function runs

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-multithreading

I made a GUI Python program with Tkinter.
I made a progressbar using "from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar".
When I press a button, I apply a function that do something and return a Boolean value.
I need that the progressbar will run until that function ends the process, and after that it will stop.

```
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
import time
import threading

wheel_flag = False
root = tk.Tk()
wheel = Progressbar(row,orient=HORIZONTAL,length=100,mode="indeterminate")


def btn_function()
  loading_function = threading.Thread(target=start_loading)
  loading_function.start()
  boolean_wheel = threading.Thread(target=some_function, args = (x,y)) #"some_function" returns a boolean value
  boolean_wheel.start()
  while True:
    if not boolean_wheel.is_alive():
      break
  wheel_flag = True


def start_loading():
  while True:
    global wheel_flag
    wheel['value'] += 10
    root.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(0.5)
        
    if wheel_flag:
        break
```

Here I don't get the boolean_wheel value, but I want to check if it true or false and send to the user message if function succeeded or not.

I want that when "btn_function" is applied, the progressbarwill start to load until "some_function" will finish run.
Now the result I get is that the loading start only after "some_function" finished, and runs without stopping until I close the program.

Comment: `target=some_function()` this is calling some_function in your main thread, remove the brackets/parentheses.

Comment: It was a copy mistake, in the original code it not exists. I fixed it here now.

Comment: you could `create minimal working` code with `button` and with example `some_function`

Comment: to update progressbar you could use `root.after(milliseconds, function)` instead of `thread` - and you could check directly `boolean_wheel.is_alive()` instead of using `wheel_flag`

Comment: `thread` can't get result from function - so function should use `global` variable to send result. OR it should use `queue` to send it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the proper solution is to remove the loop in `btn_function` and instead have `some_function` set `wheel_flag` after it is done.

```py
def some_function_wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
    global wheel_flag
    some_function(*args,**kwargs)
    wheel_flag = True
```

and call this instead of `some_function` inside your thread.

now another solution is to just run the entire `btn_function` inside another thread, by adding

```py
command= lambda : threading.Thread(target=btn_function).start()
```

inside your button definition, but nesting threads sometimes becomes hard to track.

Edited:
It works.
I checked the function value inside that function

```py
def some_function_wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
    global wheel_flag
    check = some_function(*args,**kwargs)
    if check:
      print("works")
    else:
      print("don't work")

    wheel_flag = True
```

Comment: I tried your solution. Yet it seems that ***start_loading*** function is start working after the ***some_function_wrapper*** function is ends. now it just itrate one time and then stops.

Comment: @segev_gr this is the solution to the problem in the question, this may not solve your problem because of the difference between your actual code and the code you posted, you are welcome to edit your question with your actual problem, it's likely the case that  `some_function` exits too fast that you only see 1 iteration.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `root.after(millisecond, function)` instead of `while True`-loop to run function which updates `progressbar` every few seconds. And I would use directly `boolean_wheel.is_alive()` in this function to stop updateing.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import threading

# --- functions ---

def some_function(x, y):
    time.sleep(10)
    
def btn_function():
    x = 100
    y = 100
    
    boolean_wheel = threading.Thread(target=some_function, args=(x,y))
    boolean_wheel.start()
   
    # block button
    button['state'] = 'disabled'
    
    # show progressbar
    wheel.grid(row=0, column=1)
    
    # start updating progressbar
    update_progressbar(boolean_wheel)  # send thread as parameter - so it doesn't need `global`
        
def update_progressbar(thread):
   
    if thread.is_alive():
        # update progressbar
        wheel['value'] += 10
        # check again after 250ms (0.25s)
        root.after(250, update_progressbar, thread)
    else:
        # hide progressbar
        wheel.grid_forget()
        # unblock button
        button['state'] = 'normal'

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

wheel = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient='horizontal', length=100, mode="indeterminate")
#wheel.grid(row=0, column=1)  # don't show

button = tk.Button(root, text='Start', command=btn_function)
button.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you would send widgets to functions as parameters then you could run it for many progressbars

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import threading

# --- functions ---

def some_function(x, y):
    time.sleep(10)
    
def btn_function(row, button, progressbar):
    x = 100
    y = 100
    
    boolean_wheel = threading.Thread(target=some_function, args=(x,y))
    boolean_wheel.start()
   
    start_loading(row, button, progressbar, boolean_wheel)
    
def start_loading(row, button, progressbar, thread):
    
    # block button
    button['state'] = 'disabled'
    
    # show progressbar
    progressbar.grid(row=row, column=1)
    
    # start updating progressbar
    update_progressbar(button, progressbar, thread)  # send thread as parameter - so it doesn't need `global`
        
def update_progressbar(button, progressbar, thread):
   
    if thread.is_alive():
        # update progressbar
        progressbar['value'] += 10
        # check again after 250ms (0.25s)
        root.after(250, update_progressbar, button, progressbar, thread)
    else:
        end_loading(button, progressbar)
        
def end_loading(button, progressbar):
    # hide progressbar
    progressbar.grid_forget()
    # unblock button
    button['state'] = 'normal'
    
# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

# ---

wheel1 = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient='horizontal', length=100, mode="indeterminate")
#wheel.grid(row=1, column=1)  # don't show

button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Start')
button1.grid(row=1, column=0)
button1['command'] = lambda:btn_function(1, button1, wheel1) # need to assign after creating button - to send button to function

# ---

wheel2 = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient='horizontal', length=100, mode="indeterminate")
#wheel2.grid(row=2, column=1)  # don't show

button2 = tk.Button(root, text='Start')
button2.grid(row=2, column=0)
button2['command'] = lambda:btn_function(2, button2, wheel2) # need to assign after creating button - to send button to function

# ---

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

---

I would even put it in `Frame` and create own widget `class MyProgress(tk.Frame)` to create many widgets using `for`-loop

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import threading

# --- classes ---

class MyProgrees(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, master, target_function, target_args, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.target_function = target_function
        self.target_args = target_args

        self.progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient='horizontal', length=100, mode="indeterminate")
        #self.progressbar.grid(row=0, column=1)  # don't show
        
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text='Start', command=self.on_press_button)
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
    def on_press_button(self):
        
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.target_function, args=self.target_args)
        self.thread.start()
       
        self.start_loading()
    
    def start_loading(self):
        
        # block button
        self.button['state'] = 'disabled'
        
        # show progressbar
        self.progressbar.grid(row=0, column=1)
        
        # start updating progressbar
        self.update_progressbar()
        
    def update_progressbar(self):
   
        if self.thread.is_alive():
            # update progressbar
            self.progressbar['value'] += 10
            # check again after 250ms (0.25s)
            self.after(250, self.update_progressbar)
        else:
            self.end_loading()
        
    def end_loading(self):
        # hide progressbar
        self.progressbar.grid_forget()
        # unblock button
        self.button['state'] = 'normal'
    
# --- functions ---

def some_function(x, y):
    time.sleep(10)
    
# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

# ---

x = 100
y = 100

for _ in range(10):
    widget = MyProgrees(root, some_function, (x, y))
    widget.pack(fill='x', expand=True)

# ---

root.mainloop()
```